# HTTPS No Data Received

Tags: ubuntu, https, apache2, amazon-ec2

I'm having a problem with HTTPS that I can't seem to solve on my own or with any amount of research. Occasionally, an HTTPS request will timeout and result in a "No Data Received" error. This generally happens when I'm using a virtual host redirect from HTTP to HTTPS. It does not happen every time, bot maybe 1 in 8 times, it just sits until it times out.
I am passing this through an Amazon Load Balancer then on to the server (EC2) running Apache 2 on Ubuntu 10.04.
I can't tell whether this is a redirect issue, although it doesn't seem to be. It's most likely a setup issue, so I'm going to put my setup below so you can see it.

I'd like to solve this problem as quickly as possible to any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Virtual Host file in sites-enabled for 'myurl.com'. This should force HTTPS on everything except for deploy.php.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName myurl.com
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^[A-Z]+\s/deploy.php [NC]
RewriteRule !^deploy.php https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Virtual Host file for 'myurl-ssl' in sites-enabled.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.myurl.com
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^[A-Z]+\s/deploy.php [NC]
    RewriteRule !^depoy.php https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]
    NameVirtualHost *:443
    </VirtualHost> 

    <IfModule mod_ssl.c> 
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        SSLEngine on
        ServerAdmin admin@myurl.com
        ServerName myurl.com
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/certs/myurl.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/certs/private.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/certs/AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
    SSLProtocol all
    SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM
        DocumentRoot /var/www

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
        LogLevel info
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>
```

Again, the issue appears to be something within my setup or my redirect to force HTTPS where I'll get a "No Data Received" error (324 in Chrome, but this problem occurs in every browser). I do believe it has something to do with our HTTPS setup somewhere but I can't figure out what it is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have been suffering from this issue a long time now, and it's not browser-dependent. It is relatively easy to reproduce on any browser.

The issue exists because a NAT router table overflows very easily, because it can only handle so many simultaneous connections. Modern AJAX sites, such as Facebook and Twitter use lots and lots of connections. This issue is exacerbated by the fact that most such sites nowadays use SSL connections.

Why does this exacerbate the problem?

Because SSL connections are relatively permanent after handshake, and if the *routing* is dropped by the NAT router, the browser cannot really handle the situation, and hits the long SSL time out with NO DATA or similar error. However, even this time out doesn't seem to properly reconnect and re-handshake the SSL connections in major browsers, because SSL handshake is so slow, the browsers try to reuse the existing connections as far as possible without understanding that the NAT routing related to the connection does not exist anymore.

In addition, multiple tabs to the same SSL server seem to all reuse the same TCP connection, so that closing only one tab definitely doesn't actually close the connection.

So, a workaround would be to somehow reduce the SSL NO DATA timeout, and possibly fix the browsers so that this actually erases any and all knowledge of pre-existing SSL connections, opening a totally new TCP connection to make the NAT router happy and refreshed.

I haven't yet found a practical way to solve this issue, but the bug above is definitely related to it, but it doesn't seem like the Chrome engineers understand the root cause.